# Change plot panel in multipanel plot in R

Tags: r, plot

I want to be able to follow a running simulation with multiple plots in R. The easy way to do it is to create a multi-panel plot (in my case I just use `par(mfrow = c(2,2))`), and then plot each of the four plots in turn. The problem is that it has to fully redraw the plots each time, and each time the function reaches the last (4th) panel the entire window gets redrawn. What I would like is to be able to shift back to e.g. the first panel and then plot the next points on top of the previous. If this were separate windows I could change between them with `dev.set()`, but is there something similar for panels?

Comment: `?split.screen` has some examples

Comment: It seems I could do this using `split.screen()` followed by `screen()`commands: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3151207/plot-to-specific-plot-in-multiple-plot-window?rq=1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you set up the plots to be the correct final size to begin with, you can use `par(mfg=` to switch between the panels and add to them.

An example:

```
pars <- c('plt','usr')

par(mfrow=c(2,2))

plot(anscombe$x1, anscombe$y1, type='n')
par1 <- c(list(mfg=c(1,1,2,2)), par(pars))
plot(anscombe$x2, anscombe$y2, type='n')
par2 <- c(list(mfg=c(1,2,2,2)), par(pars))
plot(anscombe$x3, anscombe$y3, type='n')
par3 <- c(list(mfg=c(2,1,2,2)), par(pars))
plot(anscombe$x4, anscombe$y4, type='n')
par4 <- c(list(mfg=c(2,2,2,2)), par(pars))

for( i in 1:11 ) {
    par(par1)
    points(anscombe$x1[i], anscombe$y1[i])
    Sys.sleep(0.5)
    par(par2)
    points(anscombe$x2[i], anscombe$y2[i])
    Sys.sleep(0.5)
    par(par3)
    points(anscombe$x3[i], anscombe$y3[i])
    Sys.sleep(0.5)
    par(par4)
    points(anscombe$x4[i], anscombe$y4[i])
    Sys.sleep(0.5)
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is much more useful than the answer in the referenced question, which suggests using split.screen() - but split.screen() has strange and unidentified behaviour if I loop back and plot on top (ref. the help file). I was getting stuck on the problem that the coordinate system gets messed up when using mfg, but this answer beautifully solves that by saving par for each plot.