# How should I display animated real-time simulation results in R?

Tags: r, animation, plot, real-time, simulation

I'm using R to run some Monte Carlo simulations, and those simulations take a fair bit of time. It would be really nice to be able to monitor the simulation results in real time along multiple dimensions. To my surprise, I haven't found a good package that does this, and each hack that I've come up with has its flaws. I'm posting this to find out whether anyone has figured out something better.

The basic issue with this sort of plot is that, while a split screen is ideal, it's tricky to get the screen to update smoothly and accurately. Simply issuing a new plot() command is amazingly slow and causes the Quartz window to flicker badly. Saving to a PDF and using Skim to view the PDF as it updates works, but it too starts to flicker before too long. There are ways to switch panels in plot() and split.screen() in order to add to plots rather than redrawing them entirely, but they have their issues: split.screen's documentation warns that "The behavior associated with returning to a screen to add to an existing plot is unpredictable and may result in problems that are not readily visible" (I've verified this).

Using a clever trick from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17410951/change-plot-panel-in-multipanel-plot-in-r), I've managed to set up a simulation monitor in base R that mostly does the trick. Here's a MWE:

```
x <- rnorm(100)
par(mfrow=c(1,2))

pars <- c('plt','usr')
plot(1, x[1], xlim=c(1,100), ylim=c(-3,3), main="x", xlab=" ", ylab=" ")
par1 <- c(list(mfg=c(1,1,1,2)), par(pars))
plot(1, x[1], xlim=c(1,100), ylim=c(-3,3), type="n", main="running mean(x)", xlab=" ", ylab=" ")
par2 <- c(list(mfg=c(1,2,1,2)), par(pars))

for(iteration in 2:100){
        par(par1)
        points(iteration, x[iteration])
        par(par2)
        segments(iteration-1, mean(x[1:iteration-1]), iteration, mean(x[1:iteration]))
    }
```

The scatterplot on the left stands in for the current state of the simulation, and the line graph on the right stands in for a plot of the parameters that I want to monitor.

This solution pretty much works. But I can't use some of the cool panel-formatting features of layout() or split.screen(), and I can't seem to figure out how to redraw one of the panels -- imagine, for example, that I wanted to track the running mean of x from 1 to 10 in the right-hand window, but then redraw the window at iteration 11 with xlim=c(1,100), plot the running means from 1 to 11, and continue to add segments up to iteration 100. I can't seem to get R to do that, perhaps (?) because the coordinate system can't be reset?

Is there a better (best?) way to do this? Thanks in advance.